# Multiprocessing a for loop in Python within a function

Tags: python, multiprocessing, threadpool, pool

This question is similar to [How to use multiprocessing in a for loop - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66333011/multiprocessing-a-for-loop-in-python)
 and [How to use multiprocessing in a for loop - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39612248/how-to-use-multiprocessing-in-a-for-loop-python)
, but neither of these solves my problem. The function `stateRecognizer()` checks if a series of images exists on current screen, using a function `getCoord(imgDir)`, and returns the corresponding state.

`getCoord(key)` returns an list of 4 integers. `getCoord(key)` returns None if the image wasn't found.

My for loop implementation

```
checks = {"loadingblack.png": 'loading',
          "loading.png": 'loading',
          "gear.png": 'home',
          "factory.png": 'factory',
          "bathtub.png": 'bathtub',
          "refit.png": 'refit',
          "supply.png": 'supply',
          "dock.png": 'dock',
          "spepage.png": 'spepage',
          "oquest.png": 'quest',
          "quest.png": 'quest'}

def stateRecognizer(hint=None):
    for key in checks:
       if (getCoord(key) is not None):
           return checks[key]
```

When I attempt to write another function and call it, it does not return the expected variable:

```
def stateChecker(key, value):
    if (getCoord(key) is not None):
        return value

def stateRecognizer():
    with Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as pool:
        result = pool.map(stateChecker, checks)
```

Outputs:

```
stateChecker() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'
```

How do I pass in a `dict` to the function `stateChecker`?

Update 2:
Thank you both @tdelaney and @Nathaniel Ford.

```
def stateChecker(key, value):
    if (getCoord(key) is not None):
        return value
def stateRecognizer():
    with Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as mp_pool:
        return mp_pool.starmap(stateChecker, checks.items())
```

The function now returns [None, None, None, None, 'bathtub', None, None, None, None, None, None] with slower processing speed (around 12 times slower).I am assuming each subprocess processes the entire dict per subprocess. Also, sometimes the function fails to read the JPEG image properly.

```
Premature end of JPEG file
Premature end of JPEG file
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
Elapsed time: 7.7098618000000005
Premature end of JPEG file
Premature end of JPEG file
[None, None, None, None, 'bathtub', None, None, None, None, None, None]
Elapsed time: 7.169349200000001
```

When with `*` before `checks.items()` or `checks`

```
    with Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as mp_pool:
        return mp_pool.starmap(stateChecker, *checks)
```

Exception raised:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
    starmap() takes from 3 to 4 positional arguments but 13 were given
```

Comment: Did you guard the main module with `if __name__ == '__main__'` like the error suggests?

Comment: Thank you that solved part 2 @flakes

Comment: You should probably break out the second problem you're getting into it's own question. There are a couple of things that may be going on, but you should isolate. Also, you may be running into a GIL issue depending on what exactly you're doing.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the concept of GIL.

Answer (score 1):

`map` calls the target function with a single parameter. Use [`starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap) to unpack an iterated tuple into parameters for the target function. Since your function is written to process key/value pairs, you can use the dictionary's item iterator to do the job.

```
def stateChecker(key, value):
    if (getCoord(key) is not None):
        return value
def stateRecognizer():
    with Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as mp_pool:
        return mp_pool.starmap(stateChecker, checks.items())
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. The function now returns ```[None, None, None, None, 'bathtub', None, None, None, None, None, None]``` with slower processing speed (around 16 times slower). I am assuming each subprocess processes the entire dict per subprocess.

Comment: The return values are entirely because `getCoord` is returning `false` for each of those keys, and only not returning `None` for `bathtub.png`. Your problem almost certainly exists in `getCoord`. Are you trying to do something like, `actually_appears_on_the_screen()`?

Comment: ```getCoord(key)``` returns None if the image wasn't found. ```actually_appears_on_the_screen()``` is what I am trying to achieve (in this case it may return True or False), but I found ```getCoord(key)```  doing the same thing where if it returns a coordinate, it is a True in the case of the first function, and vice versa.

Comment: No, the keys to be checked are fanned out to the subprocesses. Each will get `len(checks)/cpu_count()` chunks to work on. `getCoord(key)` must be returning `None` a lot for all of those `None` to be in the result list. One difference from your original, nonparallel code returns the first non-None match instead of the list you are returning with the pool. Multiprocesssing has its own overhead. Whether a task is good parallize depends on what sort or work it is doing. If this is a a fast or disk bound operation, multiprocessing will be slower.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 1):

There is a slightly uncommon behavior in Python:

```
>>> dx = {"a": 1, "b": 2}
>>> [print(i) for i in dx]
a
b
```

Essentially, only the `key` values are part of the iteration here. Whereas, if we use `items()` we see:

```
>>> dx = {"a": 1, "b": 2}
>>> [print(i) for i in dx]
a
b
```

When you call `map` on your pool, it is effectively using that first version. That means, rather than passing a key-value pair into `stateChecker` you are passing only the key. Thus your error 'missing 1 required positional argument'. The second value is missing.

By using `starmap` and `items()` we can get around this. As shown above, items will give an iterator of tuples (each a key-value pair from your dictionary).

```
def stateRecognizer():
    with Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as mp_pool:
        return mp_pool.starmap(stateChecker, checks.items())
```

`starmap` here refers to using the `*` operator:

```
>>> def f(a, b):
...   print(f"{a} is the key for {b}")
... 
>>> my_tuple = ("a", 1)
>>> f(*my_tuple)
a is the key for 1
>>> f(my_tuple)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: f() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'
```

As you can see here, when used to pass values to a function, it 'unpacks' those values, slotting each value from the tuple (or list) into an argument. You can that when we *don't* use the `*` operator, we get an error very similar to the one you originally received.

A few more notes:

When writing Python, it really is best to stick to standard naming formats. For functions, use snake case (`state_checker`) and for classes use camel case. This helps you reason faster, amongst more esoteric reasons.

This function is probably misbehaving:

```
 def stateChecker(key, value):
     if (getCoord(key) is not None):
         return value
```

Assuming that `getCoord` returns four integers in a tuple (it's unclear in the original), it's type signature is:

```
def getCoord(key: Any) -> Tuple[int, int, int, int]:
    ....
```

That means, in turn, the type signature of `stateChecker` is:

```
def stateChecker(key: Any, value: Any) -> Union[None, Tuple[int, int, int, int]]:
    ....
```

In this case it is because if your `if` clause evaluates to `false` it will return `None`. It's likely `getCoord` can be short-circuited in these cases, but without knowing more it's hard to say how. Regardless, you aren't really handling a `None` return value.